# Use VPN without changing WAN IP

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn

I'd like to connect to a VPN for file and printer sharing services at my other office, but some of the internet sites I use at home are IP white listed.

Every time I connect to the VPN, my WAN IP address changes to my office's and I'm locked out from my sites.

Is there any way to connect to a VPN but keep my internet traffic off of it, or otherwise keep my WAN address and just use the File/Printer sharing on the VPN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want split tunneling, currently you're sending all your traffic over the vpn connection. Your connection's wan ip isn't changing per se, but where your traffic appears on the internet is, so websites and such see a different ip than without the vpn.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunneling

how to do that depends on the operating system, but it's not hard (just one tickbox normally)

Comment: Is there any way to accomplish that without third party tools?

Comment: split tunneling isn't a third party tool. it's a concept. linux, Mac, Windows can all do this

Comment: Sorry, I misread the wiki article. It sounded like you needed some sort of client software. I'll do some homework on this, thanks!